# How to override object destructuring for ES class just like array destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next, es6-modules

### TL;DR

How do I make `{...myCls}` return `{...myCls.instanceVar}`?

### Actual Question

I'm trying to implement a custom version of `*[Symbol.iterator]() { yield this.internalObj; }` such that object-spreads of my class perform an object-spread operation to `myClass.instanceVar`.
Specifically, I want to make `{...(new MyClass('a', 'b'}))}` return `{...(new MyClass('a', 'b'})).innerVal}`. However, it seems [we **cannot** override object-spread logic, we can only override array-spread logic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator).

For example, this is a simple class to create an `Array` wrapper

```js
class MyArray {
    innerArray = [];

    getItem(index) {
        return (index < this.innerArray.length) ? this.innerArray[index] : null;
    }

    setItem(index, val) {
        const innerArrayLength = this.innerArray.length;

        return (index < innerArrayLength)
            ?
                this.innerArray[index] = val
            :
                this.innerArray.push(val)
        ;
    }

    removeItem(index) {
        return this.innerArray.splice(index, 1);
    }

    clear() {
        this.innerArray = [];
    }

    get length() {
        return this.innerArray.length;
    }

    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        return yield* this.innerArray;
    }
}

// Usage:
let myArr = new MyArray()   // undefined
myArr.setItem(0, 'a')   // 1
myArr.setItem(10, 'b')   // 2
console.log([...myArr])   // (2) [ 0 => "a", 1 => "b" ]
```

However, what I want is a way to do that with *object* class instance variables instead of *array* class instance variables.

For example, this is what happens when I try to implement a `StorageMock` class

```js
class StorageMock {
    storage = {};

    setItem(key, val) {
        this.storage[key] = val;
    }

    getItem(key) {
        return (key in this.storage) ? this.storage[key] : null;
    }

    removeItem(key) {
        delete this.storage[key];
    }

    clear() {
        this.storage = {};
    }

    get length() {
        return Object.keys(this.storage).length;
    }

    key(index) {
        return Object.keys(this.storage)[index] || null;
    }

    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        return yield* Object.entries(this.storage).map(([ k, v ]) => ({ [k]: v }));
    }
}

let myStore = new StorageMock()    // undefined
myStore.setItem('a', 'hello');    // undefined
myStore.setItem('b', 'world');    // undefined
console.log({...myStore});   // { storage: { a: "hello", b: "world" } }  <== PROBLEM

// Doing the same with localStorage prints out:
// { a: "hello", b: "world" }
// instead of
// { storage: { a: "hello", b: "world" } }
```

In this case, the [Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) works to spread storage entries when spreading `(local|session)Storage`, but creating a special `StorageMock` class does not.

Point being that I can't make `{...storageMockInstance} === {...(storageMockInstance.storage)}`. So how does one override the *object*-spreading syntax of an ES class?

### References/attempts

I've tried various combinations of [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), `Object.definePropert(y|ies)()`, [variants of the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in#private_fields_and_methods) (all of which have relevant access-ability defined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties)), all depending on the [`for...in` syntax defininition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) from the [generic-spreading-syntax proposal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#syntax). But all I've found is that only "standard" destructuring can be used according to references [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#enumerable_attribute), and [3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).

But there has to be a way to do this via ESNext classes. None of my attempts to accomplish the ability to use actual native class features **instead** of those available through [AMD module syntax](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/templates/amdWeb.js). It doesn't seem reasonable that I couldn't override these fields in a way similar to how other languages do so. i.e. If I could only override how the JS `for..in` loop works in the same way [that Python allows overriding it](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__), then I could spread the inner variable through a `forIn()` method just like [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) or [`toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior).

###### Note

Please do not respond with `@babel/polyfill`, `core-js`, or `babel-jest` for this question. It's not only meant for `(local|session)Storage`, but also just a question on a high-level problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

You cannot.

Unless you cheat. But might not be worth it.

### Actual answer

The term "array destructuring" might be a slightly misleading. It actually *always* starts by getting the iterator of the object and draws values from there until all bindings are satisfied. In fact, it is not only supposed to be used on arrays.

```js
const obj = { 
  *[Symbol.iterator]() { 
    yield 1; 
    yield 2; 
    yield 3; 
    yield 4; 
  } 
};

//1. take iterator
//2. take first three values
const [a, b, c] = obj;
//1. take iterator (do not continue the old one)
//2. take the first value 
const [x] = obj;

console.log(a, b, c, x); // 1, 2, 3, 1
```

Object destructuring, however, does not have a similar mechanism. When using `{...x}` the abstract operation [`CopyDataProperties`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-copydataproperties) is performed. As the name suggests, it will copy properties, rather than invoke some mechanism to get the data to copy.

The properties that will be copied would be

1. Own - not coming from the prototype.
2. A [data properties](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-data-property-attributes) as opposed to [an accessor properties](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-accessor-property-attributes) (a property defined by a getter and/or setter).
3. Enumerable.
4. Not part of the `excludedNames` parameter to the abstract operation. Note: this is only relevant when using spread with a rest target, like `const {foo, bar, ...rest} = obj;`

What could be done is to *lie* to the runtime about each of these things. This can be done using a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and you need to change the following things:

1. [`ownKeys` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/ownKeys) to switch what keys would be used for the destructuring.
2. [`getOwnPropertyDescriptor` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) to make sure the properties are enumerable.
3. [`get` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get) to give the value for the property.

This can be done as a function like this, for example and will make an object behave as if you are using one of its property values:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,  
  b: 2, 
  c: 3, 
  myProp: {
    d: 4, 
    e: 5, 
    f: 6
  }
};

const x = { ...lieAboutSpread("myProp", obj) };
console.log(x);

function lieAboutSpread(prop, obj) {
  //this will be the false target for spreading
  const newTarget = obj[prop];
  
  const handler = {
    // return the false target's keys
    ownKeys() {
      return Reflect.ownKeys(newTarget);
    },
    // return the false target's property descriptors
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, property) {
      return Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(newTarget, property);
    },
    // return the false target's values
    get(target, property, receiver) { 
      return Reflect.get(newTarget, property, receiver);
    }
  }
  
  return new Proxy(obj, handler);
}
```

So, this is *possible*. I am however, not sure it is of that much benefit to simply doing `{ ...obj.myProp }`. Moreover, the above function could be re-written in a way that does not "lie" at all. But it becomes *extremely* boring:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,  
  b: 2, 
  c: 3, 
  myProp: {
    d: 4, 
    e: 5, 
    f: 6
  }
};

const x = { ...lieAboutSpread("myProp", obj) };
console.log(x);

function lieAboutSpread(prop, obj) {
  //this will be the target for spreading
  return obj[prop];
}
```

In my opinion, this highlights why the artificial way of masking the object is an overkill.